# Is it possible to define an implementation template specialization as typedef of another type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, typedef

I have a class template for which I want to introduce several template specializations. Those template specializations identical to some existing type. Conceptually I would like to implement them as aliases/typedefs.

The following example code should show what I want to do:

```
template<class T> class Common {
    /// general implementation
};

class TypeZ;    

template<> class Common<Type1> = TypeZ; // <<< how to do this?
template<> class Common<Type2> = TypeZ;
template<> class Common<Type3> = TypeZ;
```

Is the above possible in some way in C++ (or C++11)? It would be great if I didn't have to implement `Common<...>` as a class that inherits `TypeZ` - the actual code is more complex than shown above and inheriting `TypeZ` is not a good idea there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming only certain specialisations of `Common` are aliases of `TypeZ` then you can do:

```
template<class T> class Common {
    struct type {
        /// general implementation
    };
};

template<> class Common<Type1> { using type = TypeZ; };
template<> class Common<Type2> { using type = TypeZ; };
template<> class Common<Type3> { using type = TypeZ; };

template<class T> using common_t = typename Common<T>::type;
```

Then you use `common_t<T>` rather than `Common<T>`.

Just to entertain the inheritance idea, have you tried this?

```
template<> class Common<Type1> : public TypeZ { using TypeZ::TypeZ; };
template<> class Common<Type2> : public TypeZ { using TypeZ::TypeZ; };
template<> class Common<Type3> : public TypeZ { using TypeZ::TypeZ; };
```

Then you don't need to use a nested type alias.

Comment: I'm not even sure if I fully understand that yet, but +1 for stretching my brain in a new and uncomfortable direction.

Comment: A good solution but hope for more simple. (less nested structure) It seems hard since the limit of C++ grammer)

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can, by using [type aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
template<typename T> using Common = TypeZ;
```

See the link for more examples of what is possible. `using` can be used anywhere `typedef` can be used, plus in template aliases like the above, so I recommend using `using` over `typedef` everywhere you write C++11.

---

If you need a more complicated mapping, you can use some simple template metaprogramming using [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) or [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) combined with [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).
For example, if you need to specialize for 3 types only, use [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcf56d73c3bc5366):

```
#include <type_traits>

class Type1 {};
class Type2 {};
class Type3 {};
class Type4 {};

class TypeZ {};

// Implementation 1
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_Type123_func()
{
  return std::is_same<T, Type1>() || std::is_same<T, Type2>() || std::is_same<T, Type3>();
}
template<typename T>
using Common_byfunc = typename std::conditional<is_Type123_func<T>(), TypeZ, T>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same<Common_byfunc<Type1>, TypeZ>(), "");
static_assert(std::is_same<Common_byfunc<Type2>, TypeZ>(), "");
static_assert(std::is_same<Common_byfunc<Type3>, TypeZ>(), "");
static_assert(!std::is_same<Common_byfunc<Type4>, TypeZ>(), "");

// Implementation 2
template<typename T>
struct is_Type123 : public std::conditional<std::is_same<T, Type1>() || std::is_same<T, Type2>() || std::is_same<T, Type3>(), std::true_type, std::false_type>::type {};
template<typename T>
using Common = typename std::conditional<is_Type123<T>::value, TypeZ, T>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same<Common<Type1>, TypeZ>(), "");
static_assert(std::is_same<Common<Type2>, TypeZ>(), "");
static_assert(std::is_same<Common<Type3>, TypeZ>(), "");
static_assert(!std::is_same<Common<Type4>, TypeZ>(), "");
```

Both implementations are equivalent up to a name and the fact you have to use a function call operator `()` or the member accessor `::value` in the `std::conditional`.

Comment: Please see the updated question - the template has a default implementation for all types other than `Type1/2/3`, thus a template alias won't work unfortunately :(

Comment: @zymzam: It will work with a helper trait see update.

Comment: @zymzam: as an extension for even more complicated conditions, you can nest `std::conditional`s, giving you template metaprogramming if-else. Although it's not that clear, and I would advise against it if the classification is complex.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is allow or not in C++ standard about code on this question.
In my opinion, 'using' will create a new datatype, see the sample code below.

`using TypeZ::TypeZ;` to inherit the constructor.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Base { using type_universal = T; };

//e.g. Normal template specialization
template<> class Base<int> { using type_int = int; };

//Target:
class TypeZ {public: int I_am_typeZ = 1; };

//Alias:
template<> class Base<double> : public TypeZ { using TypeZ::TypeZ; };

int main() {
    Base<double> instance;
    std::cout<<"Base<double>.I_am_typeZ = "<<instance.I_am_typeZ<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```