# Define a Specialization As Instantiation of Another Class

Tags: c++, c++14, specialization

I have a situation where I would like to define a specialization to be *the same as* the instantiation of another class.  Here's a simple example of what I want (a full intantiation in this example; in my actual problem, I want a partial specialization):

```
//Template class
template <int i> class Foo { /*...*/ };

//Another, completely different, template class
template <int i,int j> class Bar { /*...*/ };

//Ordinary specialization of Foo
template <> class Foo<0> { /*...*/ };

//Bogus specializations of Foo that
//  hopefully explain what I want.
template <> class Foo<1> = Bar<1, 11>;
template <> class Foo<2> = Bar<2, 42>;
template <> class Foo<3> = Bar<3,-71>;
...
```

What would be the advantage of doing this?  The definitions of `Foo<1>`, `Foo<2>`, etc. are fairly complicated, but easily written once as a template.  There are a lot of such definitions.  Working the definition of `Bar` into `Foo` isn't an option.  Only some values can be specialized, and the specialization of `Bar` must be hand-chosen (hence the random numbers for `int j`).

I would ordinarily achieve this effect by using CRTP.  I would make some fairly nasty modifications to `Bar`, and then do something like:

```
template <> class Foo<1> : public Bar<1, 11,Foo<1>> {};
template <> class Foo<2> : public Bar<2, 42,Foo<2>> {};
template <> class Foo<3> : public Bar<3,-71,Foo<3>> {};
...
```

Obviously, `Bar` would need to be altered, with maybe some `using` declarations to pull the constructors down.  This would be messy.

My question: can I do better than this?  That is, can a specialization be defined to be an instantiation of another template class?

---

<sup>Note: preferred standard is C++14, although later versions would be acceptable.</sup>

Comment: Should the `Foo` or `Bar` types have any knowledge of each other? That is, CRTP would allow `Bar` to "know" about `Foo` and `Foo` "knows" about `Bar` because it inherits from it (in your example). But you're wanting an essential `typedef`, so that any and all references to `Foo<1>` would be as if one wrote `Bar<1, 11>`, correct?

Comment: @txtechhelp Prettymuch. I thought about calling this question something about typedefs, but typedefs don't work afaik for specializations.¶ I'm currently writing `Bar`, so `Bar` can know about `Foo`. The base definition of `Foo` shouldn't know about `Bar`, though--only its specializations, which I am also defining.

Comment: Check out the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419869/is-it-possible-to-define-an-implementation-template-specialization-as-typedef-of) question .. might have to add a little extra, but it might get you closer?

Comment: @txtechhelp I think my question must be a dupl of that one. The accepted answer would definitely work for me. It's not nearly as elegant as I would like, but it might be marginally better than the CRTP solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would indirection help here? :)

```
template<int i> struct Indirection { using type = Foo<i>; };

template <> class Indirection<1> { using type = Bar<1, 11>;  };
template <> class Indirection<2> { using type = Bar<2, 42>;  };
template <> class Indirection<3> { using type = Bar<3, -71>; };

template<int i>
using ActualFoo = typename Indirection<i>::type;
```

Comment: Indirection solves all problems, except the problem of too much indirection.

Comment: Note that this makes template argument deduction on `ActualFoo<i>` impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use inheritance instead of CRTP.

```
template <int i> struct Foo {};

template <int i,int j> struct Bar { Bar() {} };

template <> struct Foo<0> {};

template <> struct Foo<1> : public Bar<1, 11> { using Bar::Bar; };
template <> struct Foo<2> : public Bar<2, 42> { using Bar::Bar; };
template <> struct Foo<3> : public Bar<3,-71> { using Bar::Bar; };
```

Comment: This is essentially exactly what I wrote above, but without CRTP.¶ The reason for CRTP is that e.g. `Bar<1,11>` has methods that should act like `Foo<1>`. For example, `Bar` might define `static Bar getBarPlusBar(Bar,Bar);`. Using CRTP this becomes `static FooType getBarPlusBar(FooType,FooType);`, which means I can now go `Foo<1> foo3 = Foo<1>::getBarPlusBar(foo1,foo2);`

Comment: @imallett, you have two choices. Pick the one that meets your needs the best.