# limiting template arguments to only set of classes that have different constructor signature

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, sfinae

I have a number of classes in my project that acts as a message.
and also have a template function that takes a class type and do some work with it.

```
template <typename T>
static int SendBroadcastMsg(T msg)
{
    //....do something
    return 0; //return an int result once finished.
}
```

in my main, I have a bunch of messages sent using this template. but I want to limit the template arguments to only `Message` and `AnotherMsg` types.

```
SendBroadcastMsg<Message>(1); //should be valid
SendBroadcastMsg<AnotherMsg>({ true, 2 }); //should be valid
SendBroadcastMsg<NotAMsg>(1);//shoud NOT be valid.
SendBroadcastMsg<NotAMsg>({ false, 1 });// should NOT be valid.
```

I found some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419869/is-it-possible-to-define-an-implementation-template-specialization-as-typedef-of) but I can't seem to get it working. I'm suspecting its perhaps due to the constructors of these classes have parameters in it but I'm not sure how to deal with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Full code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
struct Message
{
    Message( const int val) : Val(val) {}
    int Val;
};

struct AnotherMsg
{
    AnotherMsg( const bool  con, int val) : Cond(con), Val(val){}
    bool Cond;
    int Val;
};

struct NotAMsg
{
    NotAMsg(const int val) : Val(val),  Cond(false){}
    NotAMsg(const bool con, int val) : Cond(con), Val(val){}
    bool Cond;
    int Val;
};


//template function wrapper.
template <typename T>
static int SendBroadcastMsg(T msg)
{
    //....do something
    return 0; //return an int result once finished.
}

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_ValidMsg()
{
    return std::is_same<T, Message>(const int) || std::is_same<T, AnotherMsg>(const bool, int);
}



template <typename T>
using common_byfunc = typename std::conditional<is_ValidMsg<T>(), NotAMsg, T>::type;


static_assert(std::is_same <common_byfunc<Message>, NotAMsg>(), "");
static_assert(std::is_same <common_byfunc<AnotherMsg>, NotAMsg>(), "");

int main()
{
    SendBroadcastMsg<Message>(1);
    SendBroadcastMsg<AnotherMsg>({ true, 2 });
    SendBroadcastMsg<NotAMsg>(1);//shoud not be valid.
    SendBroadcastMsg<NotAMsg>({ false, 1 });// should not be valid.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax (a possible correct syntax) is

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_ValidMsg()
{
    return std::is_same<T, Message>::value || std::is_same<T, AnotherMsg>::value;
}
```

I mean... I don't know what do you mean with

```
std::is_same<T, Message>(const int)
```

and

```
std::is_same<T, AnotherMsg>(const bool, int)
```

but they are wrong.

If you want avoid that `SendBroadcastMsg()` is compiled with non message types, you can use `is_ValidMsg()` to SFINAE enable/disable it.

There are many ways; by example

```
template <typename T>
static std::enable_if_t<is_ValidMsg<T>(), int> SendBroadcastMsg(T msg)
{
    //....do something
    return 0; //return an int result once finished.
}
```

But remember to define  `is_ValidMsg()` before `SendBroadcasMsg()`

Another possible solution pass through the use of `is_ValidMsg()` in a simple `static_assert()` inside `SendBroadcastMsg()`

```
template <typename T>
static int SendBroadcastMsg(T msg)
{
   static_assert( is_ValidMsg<T>(), "!" );

    //....do something
    return 0; //return an int result once finished.
}
```

Comment: ah i see. I thought I had to let the compiler know the what types it takes during construction of the classes for `std::is_same.` i made the changes and certainly that compiles now. but I'm sure there are other mistakes somewhere because compiler still compiles for `SendBroadcastMsg<NotAMsg>(1);` and `SendBroadcastMsg<NotAMsg>({ false, 1 });`

Comment: @Yucel_K - you have defined `is_ValidMsg()` but you haven't used it to SFINAE enable/disable `SendBroadcastMsg()`. Answer improved.

Comment: you sir! is my hero. it works perfectly fine. just one question. (and perhaps you may want to edit your answer ) I had to change my`NotAMsg` structure to empty. when I have it with some class members and constructors, it fails to pick faulty template arguments. what would be the reason for that?

Comment: @Yucel_K - I don't know; you should prepare a full (but minimal) example to reproduce the problem. I just see a problem in `NotAMsg`: in first constructor you initialize first `Val` and then `Cond` where is defined first `Cond`. Wrong. You have to initialize the members in the order they are defined.

Comment: ooo i see. that makes sense if I could accept this more then once I definitely would.